# How do I reverse the order of the sum of arrays?

Tags: jquery, arrays

Refer to this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattmorz/yh08xfq6/) for the result. I wanted to reverse the order of the FINAL column. The snippet of the code:

```
success: function (e) {
        var t = e,
            finalAccum = []
            arr = [],
            rev = [];
        $.map(t, function (e) {
            var loc = e.location;
            var prov = e.province;
            var data = e.data;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var dataEl = data[i];
                var len = parseInt((data.length - 1) - i);
                var accumRain = parseFloat(data[i].rain_value);
                finalAccum = parseFloat(accumRain + finalAccum);
                t = dataEl.dateTimeRead;
                $('#ul2').append("<li>" + t + "</li>");
                $('#ul1').append("<li>" + accumRain + "</li>");
                $('#ul').append("<li>" + finalAccum + "</li>");
            }
        });
    }
```

What I mean with reverse is e.g. the result is 1,2,3,4,5 it should be 5,4,3,2,1.

Comment: you can use any sort function and sort in reverse order

Comment: you'll have to traverse to instances of the same Array I'm guessing. One going one way and the other in reverse

Comment: Take a look at the Fiddle, I tried getting the max length and decrements it but same result.

Comment: [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) is meant to convert every entry in an array into another one. You should be using [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) instead.

Comment: I am using `.map()` because I wanted to graph the data using Highcharts in  which data needed is array.

Answer (score 2):

simple, change the line from

`var dataEl = data[i]`

to

`var dataEl = data[data.length-i-1];`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply reverse the logic in your `for` method to iterate over the array backwards:

```
var array = $.map(t, function (i, e) {
    var loc = e.location;
    var prov = e.province;
    var data = e.data;            
    for (var i = data.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var dataEl = data[i];
        var accumRain = parseFloat(dataEl.rain_value);
        finalAccum = parseFloat(accumRain + finalAccum);
        t = dataEl.dateTimeRead;
        $('#ul2').append("<li>" + t + "</li>");
        $('#ul1').append("<li>" + accumRain + "</li>");
        $('#ul').append("<li>" + finalAccum + "</li>");
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yh08xfq6/10/)

Comment: Actually, I used `$.map` because the I need an array of data for my Highcharts.